# List of items not included in a date range filter

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, exclude-constraint

I would like to use power bi to list rooms without reservation for a selected date range.

For in stance in the attached data , if I select date range 05/17/2022 - 05/19/2022,
I would like the result list in the visualization to be:
aa
dd
ee
[image: Room reservation data]
[image: Filter for dates]